# Is it still true that C. elegans has no known natural viruses?

Tags: immunology, virology, nematode

I read in a [2009 review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2724769/) that

> While mammals and C. elegans each have a single Dicer that makes both miRNAs and siRNAs, Drosophila has two Dicers: Dcr-1 makes miRNAs, whereas Dcr-2 is specialized for siRNA production. The fly RNAi pathway defends against viral infection, and Dicer specialization may reduce competition between pre-miRNAs and viral dsRNAs for Dicer. Alternatively, Dcr-2 and Ago2 specialization might reflect the evolutionary pressure on the siRNA pathway to counter rapidly evolving viral strategies to escape RNAi. In fact, dcr-2 and ago2 are among the most rapidly evolving Drosophila genes. C. elegans may achieve similar specialization with a single Dicer by using the double-stranded RNA-binding protein, RDE-4, as the gatekeeper for entry into the RNAi pathway. However, **no natural virus infection has been documented in C. elegans**. In contrast, mammals may not use the RNAi pathway to respond to viral infection, having evolved an elaborate, protein-based immune system.

Is it still true that no know natural virus infects C. elegans? And is this [thought to be] due to the effectiveness of its [viRNA](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2703654/) (virus-derived small interfering RNAs) immunity/defense mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a natural virus, an Orsay virus.
https://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1000586
is the paper of the discovery. found by searching "virus infecting C elegans"

Comment: Indeed even has wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orsay_virus

Comment: Also the RNAi suppressors of the Orsay virus have been studied already. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3648182/ And it seems to have a novel fusion protein https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S004268221300679X

Comment: And it seems to have an egress protein https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6026750/